# Форматирование кода С в VS2010

Tags: c, форматирование

Для форматирования кода выделяют несколько разных стандартов. По какому стандарту форматирует Visaul Studio 2010?

Как наиболее удачно разделять несколько функций в коде? вставляя между ними

`/********/`

`/********/`

`/********/`

или как-то ещё?

**UPD** все привязались к комментированию кода и именам функций/переменных. Хотя вопрос иной. Если для вас это важно - все функции задокументированы doxygen'ом в .h файле,  там подробное описание каждой функции. Я же хочу узнать, как мне разделить код этих функций в .cpp файле. Не пустыми же строчками, ей-богу.

Comment: > Как наиболее удачно разделять несколько функций в коде? вставляя между ними `/********/` или как-то ещё?

Вставлять между функциями таких разделителей не нужно. Нужно просто комментировать что делает функция.

Comment: > Я же хочу узнать как мне разделить код этих функций в .cpp файле. не пустыми же строчками,ей богу.

Такой вопрос, с какой целью разделять?

Comment: >с какой целью разделять?

Задание в курсовой такое, оформить код.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет таких стандартов, регламентирующих чем нужно отделять функции друг от друга (и слава богу). Если кто-то знает, может скажет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо стараться называть функции так, чтобы было понятно что они делают без комментариев. Если не получается, то надо писать комментарии. Каждая функция должна делать только одно действие. Разделять их лучше пустой строкой. Лучше объединять функции по назначению в разные файлы, а не смешивать всё подряд.

Если редактор поддерживает регионы, то можно объединять несколько функций в группы ими. Например:

```
#pragma region Чтение
int GetValue1()
{
    ...
}

float GetValue2()
{
    ...
}
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Запись
void SetValue1(int val)
{
    ...
}

void SetValue2(float val)
{
    ...
}
#pragma endregion
```

В книге Макконнелла "Совершенный код" всё это есть. Советую почитать.

Comment: Про имена функций и комментарии. 

Стараться и добиться это две большие разницы. В реальности это совет от оторвавшихся от собственно программирования профессоров, бред которых все перепечатывают. 

На практике при использовании длинных имен теряется кристальная чистота кодируемого алгоритма.

А имена типа GetValue1 и SetValiue2 в отсутствии адекватных комментариев ничем не информативнее, чем gv1 и sv2.

--

Коротко повторюсь. Главное для функции это содержательный комментарий.

Comment: >На практике при использовании длинных имен теряется кристальная чистота кодируемого алгоритма.

 Надо алгоритм разбивать на мелкие части. Маленькие функции вряд ли будут иметь длинное имя.

>А имена типа GetValue1 и SetValiue2 в отсутствии адекватных комментариев ничем не информативнее, чем gv1 и sv2.

 Я не пытался сказать, что они информативны. Это был код, демонстрирующий регионы.

>Главное для функции это содержательный комментарий.

 Функция может измениться, и комментарий устареет.

Comment: "Функция может измениться, и комментарий устареет" - да, лучше никаких комментариев, чем неправильные. 

Точно также, если функция изменится, то ее имя и имена переменных в ней могут устареть. Обязанность программиста следить за актуальностью комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Для комментирования приоритетнее использовать xml-комменты, которые генерятся после `///`, разделение функций одной пустой строкой. Если хотите объединить несколько функций, например, все публичные, используйте регионы: `#region текст ... #endregion`.
Если же ваши функции размером более нескольких тысяч строк каждая, стоит задуматься над архитектурой.

Comment: Ой, не заметил, что вопрос для С языка... Не знаю насчет существования там регионов...

Comment: Регионы создаются через `#pragma region ... #pragma endregion`. Незнакомые прагмы компилятор всегда игнорирует. Выделением этого как отдельных регионов занимается редактор кода, а не компилятор, поэтому неважно, какой язык.

Answer (score 1):

Перед **всеми** нестатическими (extern) функциями **обязательно** делайте комментарии, причем упирайте на то **зачем нужна** функция, в каких ситуациях ее вызывают. Для сложных функций хорошо объяснить в комментарии мотивы написания данной функции и окружение в котором она "живет". Что она делает и так обычно понятно (из кода).

Расстановка скобочек, отступы, пробелы вокруг операндов - все это по здравому смыслу. Обычно настоятельно советуют всюду в программе использовать один стиль. IMHO для выделения неких смысловых  фрагментов кода стиль можно менять, но это должно быть осмысленно. Например, попытайтесь достичь того, чтобы читатель интуитивно почувствовал, что перед ним более важный фрагмент кода. Только не злоупотребляйте этим.

Тот же принцип можно использовать при именовании переменных.